# How do I pass a value into a header() function?

Tags: php, parsing, header

I have to redirect users to different pages.
So here is what I have now.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/$confirmpage')
```

But it doesn't work. It redirects them to http://www.example.com/$confirmpage (value not retrieved.) and gives 404 error.

When I use

```
echo "<script>document.location='http://www.example.com/$confirmpage';</script>";
```

It works.

But I have to use header() function for some reasons.

Comment: Depending on the contents of `$confirmpage`, you may want to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/$confirmpage")
```

If you want to refference variables in php strings, you have to use `"` instead of `'`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php